# Wordpress - How to pass error code from wp_error() to PHP exception class?

Tags: php, wordpress, exception

I am using wordpress wp_error class to handle errors.
Also when I use PHP `throw new Exception` , I find no way to pass an error code from wp_error() to Exception class.
Exception class takes second parameter as `getCode()`. However the error codes from wp_error() class are in string form.
Is there any wordpress way to handle such issue?
Also if I extend exception class, where should I place it? What's the best hook.

```
try{

        $error = new WP_Error();

        //Some validation

        if(is_wp_error()){
            $error_code = $error->get_error_code(); //returns "my-error-code" (String)
            throw new Exception( "Error thrown"); //How to send error code
        }   
    } catch{
        //Receive error code here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In `catch()` you can get Exception object. From that you can get the error detail. Check following example.

```
try {
    $error = new WP_Error( 'custom-error', 'This is custom error.' );
    if (is_wp_error( $error )) {
        $error_code = $error->get_error_code();
        throw new Exception( $error_code );
    }
} catch ( Exception $e) {
    // $e will hold the error object.
}
```